# "No such payment intent: (null)" on Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I recently updated Stripe iOS SDK and API from 2019-05-16 version to the latest one. Previously my code was working fine with Charges API, but having issue with PaymentIntents now.

I work with Stripe Connect and custom accounts while creating separate charges and transfers.

The problem is that I get *No such payment intent: (null)* error when I attempt to make the initial payment. But a payment intent, in fact, is being created. The payment is "incomplete" and "PaymentIntent status: requires_payment_method".

On the other hand, if I manually replace the *(clientSecret)* that is passed from **MyAPIClient.swift/createCustomerKey** method to **CheckoutViewController.swift/paymentContext(didCreatePaymentResult)** method, with another clientSecret key from a previously incomplete charge, it all works fine and the payment is successful.

I can confirm that clientSecret key is being correctly passed from my server (Firebase Cloud functions) to client, and then from MyAPIClient to CheckoutViewController - see print()'s in the code below. I also double checked the API keys on front and back end.

Here is my backend code:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);

exports.createPaymentIntentForStripeAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const uid = req.body.uid;
    const amount = req.body.amount;
    const currency = req.body.currency;
    const customer_id = req.body.customer_id;
    const transfer_group = req.body.transfer_group;

    return stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: amount,
        currency: currency,
        customer: customer_id,
        transfer_group: transfer_group,
        capture_method: "manual",
    }).then(function(paymentIntent) {
        const clientSecret = paymentIntent.client_secret;
        res.status(200).json(clientSecret);
    });

});
```

Client side:

```
// MyAPIClient

    func createPaymentIntent(amount: Int, bookingID: String, completion: @escaping ((Result<String>) -> Void)) {

        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("createPaymentIntentForStripeAccount")
        let transfer_group = bookingID.components(separatedBy: "/").last!
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "uid": UserService.currentUserProfile!.uid,
            "customer_id": UserService.currentUserProfile!.stripe_customer_id!,
            "amount": amount,
            "transfer_group": transfer_group,
            "currency": "USD"
            ]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseString { responseString in
                switch responseString.result {
                case .success(let clientSecret):
                    print(clientSecret)
                    completion(.success(clientSecret))
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
        }
    }


// CheckoutViewController

    func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPPaymentStatusBlock) {

        MyAPIClient.sharedClient.createPaymentIntent(amount: self.paymentContext.paymentAmount, bookingID: self.bookingRef.url) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let clientSecret):
                let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: clientSecret)
                paymentIntentParams.configure(with: paymentResult)
                print(clientSecret)
                STPPaymentHandler.shared().confirmPayment(withParams: paymentIntentParams, authenticationContext: paymentContext) { status, paymentIntent, error in
                    switch status {
                    case .succeeded:
                        completion(.success, nil)
                    case .failed:
                        completion(.error, error)
                    case .canceled:
                        completion(.userCancellation, nil)
                    @unknown default:
                        completion(.error, nil)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed to create a Payment Intent: \(error)")
                completion(.error, error)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion or feedback will be welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above code produces clientSecret in double quotes, resulting in a key that looks like ""pi_xxx_secret_xxx"", which of course doesn't work.

I should either escape the extra quotes after parsing JSON on the server side, or remove them on the client side. For example:

```
completion(.success(clientSecret.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: ""))
```